# Running JNLP on Page Load

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jnlp

I want to run a JNLP file on page load using javascript.

Internet explorer runs JNLP without any problem, but Chrome downloads JNLP.

But if I click on link manually chrome runs JNLP, also.

**Is there a solution to run a JNLP on page load without any manual click, on chrome?**

Here is my example code:

```html
<head>
<script>
    function codeAddress() {
        document.getElementById('mylink').click();
    }

    window.onload = codeAddress;        
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="mylink" target="_self" href="http://localhost/projects/myjnlp.jnlp">go</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Does the site return the correct content-type for JNLP files?

Comment: Yes, content type is jnlp.

Comment: *"content type is jnlp"*  DYM **literally** the site returns `jnlp`?  Because that is wrong.  It is a file extension, **not a content type.**

Comment: sorry, i missunderstood your answer.

web page's contenttype is text/html but destination file is directly a jnlp file. like sample code above.

Comment: *"i missunderstood your answer"*  My 'answer' was a comment not an answer, and you still don't seem to understand.  The content type of HTML is `text/html` & **the content type of JNLP is `application/x-java-jnlp-file`.**  Does the server return the correct content type for the JNLP?  One way to check it is to use JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: sorry, i'm really beginner in stackoverflow. I will check my jnlp file, test again and then inform you. because now i don't have access to my development environment.

Comment: OK.. let me know when you have an update.  Looks you've been trying to solve this since February, so it does not seem like a rush job.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is not a matter of correct code but a matter of Chrome configuration. We have a similar problem with an application we rolled out for one of our customers. JNLP files are not trusted by default thus the JNCP file is downloaded by Chrome and then the user is asked whether to keep or discard the file.

Once the user keeps the file we are able to choose "Always Open Files of This Type" in the menu of the downloaded item. See the following screenshot for reference:

[image]

In our case the applications runs on Intranet we can help our users configuring chrome correctly. In your case however I suggest that you use jQuery to determine the browser and show an instruction box on the lower left corner of the window (where the download item will show up).

Assuming you have a hidden DIV on the lower left corner of your page and you have already included the [jQuery browser plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin):

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 
if($.browser.chrome){
    $('#chromeInstructions').show();
}
```

Comment: Hello Matthias, now that Chrome has disabled the option 'Always open files of this type', did you manage to find a workaround for your customer? If yes, please kindly share. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple solution. Prefix the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag with the `jnlp:` scheme/protocol, like `href="jnlp:XXX"`. For example, based on the OP's example, this works:

```
<a id="mylink" href="jnlp:http://localhost/projects/myjnlp.jnlp">go</a>
```

Tested on Chrome v89.0.4389.72.

Answer (score 0):

No, Chrome cannot. Latest Chrome no longer provide "Always open files of this type". This option is disabled and in grey.

In IE11, your sample code does not open JNLP file automatically on page load, it asks for download instead. Even though the content type is "application/x-java-jnlp-file". But if I click the "Go" href manually, it works perfect. IE open the JNLP file and run the web start application automatically.

To make IE11 works again, you can add the site to Intranet zone which security level is medium low. (Internet options --> Security --> intranet).